# Intermittent saving issues on production server .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, windows-server-2012

Right we have a standard form that posts a model to the endpoint and saves/updates the data in the database. Locally the form works every time and updates the model and thus the database. On the production server however, the saving is intermittent, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. When it fails, the page reloads with the newly added data, but after an additional GET request of the page the old data is displayed again.

Ive logged the POST data at various points, everything required is being sent to the endpoint even when failing to send. What i can get my head round is why sometimes it saves and sometimes it doesn't.

using: MS Windows Server 2012, ASP.NET MVC 4, IIS 7.5

Pretty stuck on where to look next to track down the issue? Any help in tracking down the issue will be greatly appreciated!

Here is the form in question:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-row" style="margin-top: 60px;">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName, Model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.LastName, Model.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateOfBirth, Model.DateOfBirth)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)
    </div>
    <div class="form-row bottom-line">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Gender)
        @Html.RadioButtonForEnum(m => m.Gender, "gender-wrapper")
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Headline)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Headline, Model.Headline)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Headline)
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Industry)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Industry, (SelectList)ViewBag.Industries, new { @class = "industry-select" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Industry)
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Position)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Position)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="save" />
    }
```

And the endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Settings([ModelBinder(typeof(DateTimeModelBinder))]UserSettingsViewModel model)
{
    var user = userService.LoadUser(User.UserId);
    ViewBag.Industries = new SelectList(userService.GetAllIndustries(), "Name", "Name", user.Industry);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Mapper.Map(model, user);
        userService.UpdateUser(user);
        model = Mapper.Map<User, UserSettingsViewModel>(user);
    }
    else //leave the model intack to correct errors, just set the other tab data
    {
        model.Education = Mapper.Map<IList<UserEducation>, IList<EducationViewModel>>(user.UserEducations.ToList());
        model.Employment = Mapper.Map<IList<UserEmployment>, IList<EmploymentViewModel>>(user.UserEmployments.ToList());
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Also have a custom model binder to create the datetime from the day,month,year drop down lists and a custom editor for the datetime type. Can show these if needed too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as I see it is that right now you have an issue with an N-tier system but you don't know in what tier the issue exists. The very first thing I would do is start SQL profiler on the database & run a trace while the issue is happening. If you don't see any communication when the failure occurs then this is good as you've probably eliminated 50% of the potential issues and can focus on the mvc app.

If on the other hand the data is being sent to the db the same in all cases then you know the issue lies with your database code.

Comment: This still doesnt explain why it works flawlessly locally, and not on the server, which leads me thinking its a configuration issue over the code. Will get out a profiler and see what i can find.

Comment: updates: ran a profiler on the server, can confirm the correct sql is being sent to the database. However on one occasion the updated sql was sent and evident in the sql parameters, on the next occasion the sql didnt contain the updates.

Comment: any ideas from the recent info?